# I am not able to make connection to database having SQL Server in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel-5.3

I am trying to connect to database having SQL Server DBMS but my connection is unsuccessful with following error in the screen shot?

[image: Error]

This is the code I am having:

```
public function getTest(Request $request)
    {
        $db_ext = DB::connection('sqlsrv');
        $user = $db_ext->table('HR.DtlEmployeeDetails')->get();
        print_r($user);

    }
```

Comment: Check the EventViewer where SQL is installed for errors (maybe the user cannot access the SQL?), Post your connection.

Comment: 'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_SQL_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_SQL_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_SQL_DATABASE', 'boc_db'),
            'username' => env('DB_SQL_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_SQL_PASSWORD', ''),
            'prefix' => '',
           
        ],this is how i define in the database.php in laravel

Comment: 1. Update your question with this new info. 2. Open Sql Server Manager and try to connect to **localhost** (I think it **not exist**) with _root_ user and without password (this are the infos you typed...)